# MSSQL Reporting Server slow on first connection

Tags: ms-sql

I'm relatively new to the MSSQL world, and we have a newly installed reporting server that is in an availability group. The first time any report is executed, it seems to take about 30-40 seconds to bring the results back.
I know this is some sort of connection issue because subsequent execution of the reports are quick. If the connection is idle for some time, it seems to try and make the connection again and takes the 30-40 seconds.

Is this normal behavior and is there a work around?

Answer (score 0):

It's "normal" that SSRS takes more time to load the first time you access it after a long time of inactivity. The issue is caused by the way how SSRS works and SSRS regularly restarts application domain after a specific time period. After the application domain is restarted, then upon first request to the SSRS it needs to load all the settings and it takes quite a long time.

Schedule the execution of the following PowerShell script out of the business hours, each morning before business hours or at lunch time, and after that you will have SSRS ready without any delays.

So here is the PowerShell script:

```
Stop-Service "SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)"
Start-Service "SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)"
$wc = New-Object system.net.webClient
$cred = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
$wc.Credentials = $cred
$src = $wc.DownloadString("http://localhost/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx
```

For more explicit instructions please read [this](https://pawlowski.cz/2011/07/31/solving-issue-long-starting-report-ssrs-2008/) article.